# LoadingWindow with animation

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I need to create loading window. Some splash screen that appears while main window is initializing and loading.

But my loading window contain animations and so on. So, everything, and from ctor too I need to make through Dispatcher. And as a result - system wait while main window is loaded than show loading window for a moment and then show main window....

And there is no sense in loading window at all :)

So, how to make my loading window in right way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just IMO; A complex splash screen that itself takes lots of time to load is sort of missing the point.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use Multi-threading. Here is msdn on threads

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/798axes2.aspx

and a tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

and another one specifically for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446493.aspx

Comment: Of course, I'm using multi-threading, but all operations with GUI must be done through Dispatcher. As a result - mainWindow and LoadingWindows work in the same (GUI) thread. And no result...

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance

Comment: If my answer worked for you and you liked it maybe you could accept it

Comment: Unfortunatley, there is very old article for WinForms and .NET 1.0 .... it just about some special "splash form", not thew thing I need, sorry. I just made my loadingWindow as Main and load real MainWindow from it... it's ok for me for now :)